# input:not([type="checkbox"]) not working in angular test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-mocha

Below is my compiled template in beforeEach function

```
template = '<form name="configForm">' +
                  '<input type="number"/>' +
                  '<input type="checkbox"/>' +
                  '<input type="text"/>' +
                  '<div class="form-error" ng-show="configForm.$error.max">Error</div>' + 
                  '</form>';
element = angular.element(template);   
element = $compile(element)($scope);
```

Why is below find method returning me empty results?

```
var dirElementInput = element.find('input:not([type="checkbox"])');
console.log(dirElementInput); 
console.log(dirElementInput.length);
```

But when i use it like this, it works:

```
var dirElementInput = element.find('input');
console.log(dirElementInput); 
console.log(dirElementInput.length);

Object{0: <input type="number">, 1: <input type="checkbox">, 2: <input type="text">, length: 3}

LOG: 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQueryLite that Angular uses, the `find()` method is **limited to finding by tag name**, so you cannot use `:not` here like you would in the full jQuery library....

An alternative would be to write a small method to filter the input types.

For reference, here's the [Angular Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) on `find()`.

Answer (score 1):

AngularJs uses jQlite for DOM manipulation which is a lightweight implementation of the jQuery DOM manipulation library. The problem is that jQlite doesn't support those complex selector, according to the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element):

> `find()` - Limited to lookups by tag name
>
> `angular.element` - Keep in mind that this function will not find elements by tag name / CSS selector. For lookups by tag name, try instead `angular.element(document).find(...)` or `$document.find()`, or use the standard DOM APIs, e.g. `document.querySelectorAll()`.

Therefore, if you want to use complex selector you can use jQuery instead, or use `documento.querySelector()`.

For using AngularJs with jQuery instead of jQlite, you can use the [`ngJq`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngJq) directive, this way angular will look to `window.jQuery` instead of its internal jQlite.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app ng-jq="jQuery">
...
...
</html>
```

Or in the last case you can always fallback to javascript:

```
var inputs = angular.element(document).find('input');

var nonCheckBoxArray = [].filter.call(elements, function(elm) {
    return elm.type != 'checkbox';
});

var inputsNonCheckBox = angular.element(nonCheckBoxArray);
```